# hardhat: want to test an emit event that is in a library

Tags: events, hardhat, library, test, chai

file Library

```
library Events {
    error Mint();
}
```

file Contract calling the event

```
emit Event.Mint()
```

**Can't get Chai detect the event that is in the library**

Throw this error in both cases: **AssertionError: Event "Events.Mint" doesn't exist in the contract**

try:

```
await expect(contract.connect(minter).mint(data)).to.emit(contract, 'Events.Mint')
```

or

```
await expect(contract.connect(minter).mint(data)).to.emit(contract, 'Mint')
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

When you have a contract that emits an event in an underlying library instead of the contract itself, since the contract doesn't contain the ABI of the event you probably face this error:

`AssertionError: Expected event "MyEvent" to be emitted, but it doesn't exist in the contract. Please make sure you've compiled its latest version before running the test.`

to fix it you can create a contract instance with the library ABI (The one that contains the event) and the contract address.

it's possible in two ways:

**contractInstance** `is the instance with the contract ABI`

**MyEvent** `is the event emits in the library`

**EventLibrary** `is the library that emits the event`

**EventLibraryInstance** `is the library instance that has been used in deploying the contract`

**contractInstanceWithLibraryABI** `is the instance with the library ABI and the contract address`

first:

```
let contractInstanceWithLibraryABI = await ethers.getContractAt("EventLibrary", contractInstance.address, signer)

await expect(
     await contractInstance.myFunction()
).to.emit(contractInstanceWithLibraryABI, "MyEvent")
```

second:

```
contractInstanceWithLibraryABI = await EventLibraryInstance.attach(
    contractInstance.address
)

await expect(
     await contractInstance.myFunction()
).to.emit(contractInstanceWithLibraryABI, "MyEvent")
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/11137/watching-events-defined-in-libraries), it is possible to by defining the event in your main contract as well. Here is an example:

```js
library EventEmitterLib {
    function emit(string s) {
        Emit(s);
    }
    
    event Emit(string s);
}

contract EventEmitterContract {
    using EventEmitterLib for string;
    
    function emit(string s) {
        s.emit();
    }
    
    event Emit(string s);
}
```

However, I'm confused because your event is actually an `error` in a library named `Event`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was trying to group all the events in a separate file. So I made the library. Finally, I decided to continue incluiding the events in the contract.

Comment: I was doing the same approach with errors (including all in a separate file in a library) and chai is working ok. I thought that I was doing a mistake.